# Automatically apply patches when updating plugins

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-neobundle

I want to be able to automatically apply my personal patches to plugins when they are updated.

For example, I would like to apply [this patch](https://github.com/dalejung/vim-fugitive/commit/21b91d4c18dcdf2a6292a172ab09776d41a6b715) every time the `vim-fugitive` plugin is updated.

I am using [neobundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim) to manage my plugins, and would like to be able to do `:NeoBundleCheckUpdate` and have the latest upstream changes pulled, and then my patches / commits applied, and then have `vim` use the result.

Is there a way to automatically apply patches to plugins when they are updated upstream?

Answer (score 2):

Note that Neobundle is [not maintained by its author anymore](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/blob/master/README.md), it has been replaced by [Dein.vim](https://github.com/shougo/dein.vim)

In Dein.vim you have a post update hook option available (see [`:h dein-options-hook_post_update`](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim/blob/master/doc/dein.txt#L840-L843)) which allows you to execute a function after a plugin is updated.

You can then create a function (in vim or with an external tool) which will apply the patch you want.